Altium edit multiple symbols at once
I've been working with Altium for a while and have always been a bit frustrated with how libraries work.
I currently need to update the symbol of several components, for example adding a text to all capacitors to indicate the voltage rating (taken from the component parameters). All the capacitors I used have been created one by one, copying a template symbol and populating the parameters and suppliers with the Manufacturer Part Search.

Is there a reasonably fast way to update several symbols at once?
More in general, I would really appreciate some feedback from the
experts on how to manage this kind of situation (if any exists)
and/or hear your library workflow!

Thank you!

Altium supports many different library management strategies, and to be able to advice on method for q1 you have to tell us how your library is managed.
q2 is more opinion based and imo not so relevant on this site.

It sounds to me that what you want is a database library - where components with the same schematic symbol refers to one schlib, and components with the same footprint refer to the same pcblib

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

@Yaxit, what version of altium?

Thank you for the resources, I will look into the database library and the forum. But as I understand then I need to make a new library either way.
